# How do I formulate this sentence in a formal mathematical way?

Tags: notation, formal-languages

How do I formulate this sentence in a formal mathematical way: "$\delta x$ is the largest band in $x$ that satisfies $f(x) < 1/2$"? That is, how do I define $\delta x$?

Take the following figure as an example, where $x$ goes from 0 to 20. We have $\tilde{\delta}x_1 = 5 -3=2$ and $\tilde{\delta}x_2 = 10 -6=4$. Therefore $\delta x = \max [\tilde{\delta}x_i] = \tilde{\delta}x_2 = 4$.

[image]

P.S.: my $f(x)$ is not actually an analytical equation, it is a series of discrete points obtained from a numerical problem.

Comment: You can say $\delta_x$ is the largest _interval_ where $f(x)<\frac{1}{2} \forall{x}\in{\delta_x}$

Comment: I would just say "$\delta_x$ is the size of the largest interval on which $f(x)<\frac12$". Like @eminem, I prefer $\delta_x$ to $\delta x$.

Comment: But I need something showing explicitly how to calculate $\delta x$. Yes, @TonyK,, it could be simply $\delta$.

Comment: You could say something like $\delta_x = \sup \{\beta - \alpha \mid \alpha, \beta \in \Bbb R, \forall x \in (\alpha, \beta), f(x) < 1/2\}$. But this doesn't really serve any purpose at all. It's a common misconception that writing things with more symbols makes it more rigorous, which is only true in *very* specific contexts such as doing foundational mathematics in formal systems. It's fine to use what the other commenters suggested, and is in fact much more informative. If you question is *how to calculate* $\delta_x$ for some data set, you should ask that, but probably not here.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen, I totally agree with you, but I was demanded to write this with the symbology. Could you explain a little bit more how does this notation that you used defines $\alpha$ and $\beta$ the limits of the intervals $\tilde{\delta}x_i$?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen, also I think you should "answer the question" so that I can accept your answer.

Comment: But @IzaakvanDongen showed you that formula as an example of what _not_ to do! There is nothing imprecise about what eminem and I suggested.